# AVR32/GCC Linker warning: input is not relaxable

Tags: gcc, avr32, avr32-gcc

I am trying to compile an AVR32 program with GCC 3.4.2 and getting the following linker warning:

`input is not relaxable`

Could someone explain what that warning means?

*Linker flags*: `-Wl,--start-group  -Wl,--end-group -Wl,--gc-sections -mpart=uc3c0512c -Wl,--relax -Wl,-e,_trampoline`

Answer (score 1):

From [Atmel](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/AppNotes/doc32074.pdf)

> Linker relaxing is enabled in the linker by passing the ‘—relax’
>   option to the linker. If  using GCC as a frontend for the linker, this
>   option is automatically passed to the linker  when using ‘-O2’ or
>   ‘-O3’ or explicitly using the ‘-mrelax’ option. Marking the output 
>   objects from GCC as relaxable is done by giving the assembler the
>   ‘--linkrelax’ option.  This option is automatically passed on to the
>   assembler from GCC when using ‘-O2’ or ‘-O3’ or explicitly using the
>   ‘-mrelax’ option.

Perhaps you didn't pass the needed options to the assembler for the `--relax` option to work in the linker.